# How to calculate size for 2nd partition for Link2SD / Apps2SD?

Tags: sd-card, storage, 6.0-marshmallow, app2sd, link2sd

I've moved to Marshmallow (CM13) and unwittingly fallen victim to its [regression in support for apps stored on the external SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138356/85865) (since adopting external SD as storage is not option), so now I'm told I need to use [Link2SD](http://www.link2sd.info/) or [Apps2SD](http://www.apps2sd.info/) to move app files to my external card.

There is plenty of information online on why and how a second SD card partition is used by Link2SD or Apps2SD (not least [the Link2SD FAQ](http://www.link2sd.info/faq)), but I can't find any guidelines anywhere for how to determine the best size for the partition when first creating it.  Presumably this depends on how many apps I want to put on SD, and the nature of those apps.  So rather than asking for some highly subjective rules of thumb, I'll ask a more precise question:

How can I calculate how big I would need to make this second partition in order to accommodate moving all of my currently installed and movable apps to it?  In other words, **is there an easy way to calculate a total size of all the app parts which Link2SD or Apps2SD would be able to move to SD?**

There are two parts to the question:

1. Which components will it actually move?  All the info online seems horribly confusing.  AFAICS it will move the apk, dex, and lib files, but what about the internal data and cache files?  I've also heard about obb files - do I need to include them in calculations too?
2. How can I conveniently add up the sizes of all those to get a total which gives me an idea how big my second partition should be? e.g. if the total was 1.4GB, I would know that creating a second partition of around 2GB would probably be fairly future-proof.

   I know Link2SD and Apps2SD both let me filter the app list to only show movable apps, and for each app they also displays the size of the apk/dex/lib/data/cache on internal storage.  But adding these all up across my 71 movable apps would be extremely tedious.  Is there is some cunning CLI command I can run locally via a shell to add these numbers up? e.g. something based on piping the output of `pm list packages` or similar into `awk`?

BTW I don't have any particular preferences for Link2SD or Apps2SD so answers involving either would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: I could be incorrect if it has changed very recently (a quick Google search didn't turn up a different answer as of this posting), but APP2SD and Link2SD do not support Marshmallow or CM13. So your question(s) may be a mute point.

Comment: I had already seen reports of people using at least one of them successfully on Marshmallow, e.g. http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/link2sd-t3222034/post64400093#post64400093  BTW I think you meant 'moot' not 'mute' ;-)

Comment: lol... yes, moot was what I meant. Read through the thread, it looks like a lot of work and spotty success that isn't consistent... Using the split adopted method looks better IMO, where you can say XX% is external storage and XX% is internal (adopted) storage. http://blog.sam.liddicott.com/2016/02/android-6-semi-adopted-storage.html

Comment: Adopting my SD card is not an option for [reasons already explained](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/138356/85865).