# How can I know the name of my SD card

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, sd-card

I have read this thread :

[How can I move apps to SD on non-adopted Marshmallow storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138356/119358)

Now, I have a question about this. How can I know the name of my SD card, I want to follow one of the answer.
And, he says that is SD card is `disk:179_64`, but how can I know which name has mine ?

And By the way, I named it as **SD CARD**. Is that what its name is ?

Answer (score 0):

On the answer, it says to run

```
adb shell sm list-disks adoptable
```

To get the name of your SD card.

This requires you to setup adb (a google search will provide instructions) and you would run that command from a computer.

A possibly easier way is to download a terminal app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm and run the commands, omitting the `adb shell`

Comment: @DarkDarkai dark or you can do this even from terminal emulator. Just type 'sm list-disks' and hit enter

Comment: Oh on adb it didn't showed any disks but the teminal emulator did so now i can try the rest i'll recoment if i'll keep commenting here if i have another problem