# Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Thread Binder_C gave up waiting for partitionMixed after 180000ms

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, app2sd, java, sony-xperia-m-dual

After entering the final command to make a mixed-format SD card in [How can I move apps to SD on non-adopted Marshmallow storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143041/94084):

> $ adb shell sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 25

I meet this error:

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Thread Binder_C gave up waiting for partitionMixed after 180000ms

If it is `75`, then the error is:

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Thread Binder_4 gave up waiting for partitionMixed after 180000ms

How can I fix this? Only 3 results appear in Google, and neither of them helps.

- **Phone**: Sony Xperia M4 Aqua Dual
- **SD card**: SanDisk Ultra micro SDHC UHS-1 Card 16 GB, class 10

Comment: Sounds like it is taking more than 3 minutes to partition.  That shouldn't be the case, it's probably hanging for some reason.  That said, what device do you have and what class and size of SD card?

Comment: @MatthewRead I have updated my question

Comment: You need to eject (unmount) the card first from Settings - Storage. Then follow this: [How to turn a portable SD card into internal storage via ADB command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38044532).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the SD card is mounted to have an ext4 partition (alongside with another normal partition), in order to use Link2SD to force moving unmovable apps to SD card. The error shows up after this. Even reformatting the SD card to have only one full partition back does not solve the problem.

To solve it, reformatting it **with the phone's default format tool**. You may want to reboot the phone after done. Thereafter, you can partition the disk with adb as normal.