# Does ZTE prevent the use of adoptive storage with Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I was trying to format a 32 GB Samsung SD card for adoptive storage in a ZTE Z815 running Marshmallow, but the only option is portable. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Your device [doesn't have](https://androidforums.com/threads/new-sd-card-almost-useless.1146679/) this feature enabled by OEM . Similar to other models as you can see from [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=zte+z815+adoptable+storage&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=-Co2WdLrHMmCvQSBgQ0) and for another ZTE model [Convert portable SD to Internal SD where option is unavailable](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172594/131553)

Same is the case with some Samsung devices. You would need to search at places like XDA for workaround like [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/zte-grand-x-4-adoptable-storage-t3509134)

Also see this question for workarounds

[How can I move apps to SD on non-adopted Marshmallow storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138356/how-can-i-move-apps-to-sd-on-non-adopted-marshmallow-storag)